# How to simply create controls dynamically and retrieve their values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

- I have a dropdownlist with options "1", "2", and "3".
- The user selects an option and presses a button.
- Based on what number they chose, 1, 2 or 3 textboxes will be created dynamically with IDs textBox_1, textBox_2, textBox_3 (for example).
- The user will then input into each textbox and press another button and the values of these textboxes are validated and saved.

Could someone please provide code on how to do this (seemingly very simple) task?  I have asked two lengthy questions already on my actual project, that seem to have been  misunderstood or I have gotten the wrong end of the stick (including the creation of the textboxes on Page_Load/Page_Init use of repeaters etc).

This needs to be done dynamically because in my project there are many controls and this number can vary.  I can post my code so far if needs be, but in the other questions this seems to have confused matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question: what if the controls are already created, should it be possible to create more than the available number in the dropdown(f.e. 3 +3)?

Assuming you allow to create more than the number of controls, you need to

- handle the Button's `Click` event
- add these controls to a placeholder or panel(container control) on the page with the correct id according to their number(f.e. `textBox_4`)
- store the total number of controls in a `ViewState` or `Session` variable
- recreate these controls in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` (at the latest) with the same ID as before

Then you've ensured that ViewState gets loaded and events are triggered.

Here's  code which demonstrates what i mean:

[load dynamic control from a dropdownlist event handler, how to preserve the control after button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266482/load-dynamic-control-from-a-dropdownlist-event-handler-how-to-preserve-the-cont/5266670#5266670)

Comment: I have placeholds setup that help determine the layout of all of the textboxes and labels (6 in total per 'row' upto 10 rows at the moment).  I have no idea as to the syntax (or even the logic) of 'creating' these at Page_Init as when the page initialises I don't know how many to create.  I also do not know how to store the number of controls in viewstate.  Apologies, I am a relative novice at VB/ASP.net).

Comment: @Ryan: Here's a former answer which demonstrates it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266482/load-dynamic-control-from-a-dropdownlist-event-handler-how-to-preserve-the-cont/5266670#5266670

Comment: Well the example you have linked to has worked so far (I have made the example work in its own panel within my project) so I imagine I can adapt my code to work with it.  Thanks for your help Tim, I'll mark yours as the answer to this.  Hopefully be able to draw a line under this annoying project soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Code For creating Dynamic textboxes:

```
Protected Sub ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If ((Not (ddl.SelectedValue) Is Nothing)  _
                AndAlso (Integer.Parse(ViewState("count").ToString) <> 0)) Then
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i <= Integer.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue))
            Dim t As TextBox = New TextBox
            t.ID = ("TextBox_" + i)
            form1.Controls.Add(t)
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
    ElseIf ((Not (ddl.SelectedValue) Is Nothing)  _
                AndAlso (Integer.Parse(ViewState("count").ToString) > 0)) Then
        Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(ViewState("count").ToString)
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i <= Integer.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue))
            Dim t As TextBox = New TextBox
            t.ID = ("TextBox_" + id)
            form1.Controls.Add(t)
            id = (id + 1)
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

and in page load add this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

If Not IsPostBack Then
           ViewState("count") = 0
         End If
     End Sub

To validate the data, add a button control to your page ( I will add the code shortly )

Comment: Any chance I could have this in VB to test?  I tried converting it online but it couldn't be converted.

Comment: You need to store the number of already created controls somewhere and you need to recreate them on postbacks. Otherwise this won't work.