# Dynamic controls missing in asp.net application on postback event of dynamic control

Tags: asp.net

Hi I'm adding dynamic Controls on button click event,In that I hav dropdown control, I'm raising an event to drop down for selected index change, I made auto post back true, When I'm selecting new item from drop down I'm Losing all the dynamic controls

Comment: show your code and at which event you are adding controls?? use Page_Init()

Comment: I added it in button click event protected void lnkbtnAddInverter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicControls();
    }

Comment: You need to recreate all of your dynamic controls on every postback in Page_Init or Page_load. Therefore you just have to persist the number of already creted controls across postbacks, for example in ViewState or Session.

Comment: Thanks Niranjan it worked for me, but I got a problem for that I want capture button click event in page_Init, any thats also resolved.   thanks all once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every server control that inherits **IPostBackDataHandler** interface has a **LoadPostData** method that processes the postback data. When control is implemented by a class (page, form, placeholders, controls etc), that class calls the **LoadPostData** method and passes the posted data and key **to maintain control states**.

All you **need to do is to re-instantiate / reinitialize dynamic controls before or within page load event each and every time during postback** and add this control to page / forms / placeholders. Then the posted data will automatically be assigned to the control by calling the LoadPostData method by the parent control and control event will fire.

check the article and how to write code for dynamic control -
***[How to maintain dynamic control events, data during postback in asp.net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/09/maintain-dynamic-control-events-data-during-postback.html)***

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate all dynamically created controls on every postback(in load event at the latest).
You also have to ensure that they get the same ID as before to trigger events and maintain ViewState.

If you know the number of controls to create(which could be stored in `ViewState`) you can derive the ID from the counter variable by appending it to the control-id. Then you can recreate them with the correct ID  in page's `init` event.

Recommandable readings:

- [TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
- [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Or you use one of the builtin [Data-Bound Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) that do this automatically. You only have to set their `DataSource` and call `DataBind`().

Here are answers of me on similar questions with implementations:

- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276160/284240)
- [VB.NET (+ C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266482/load-dynamic-control-from-a-dropdownlist-event-handler-how-to-preserve-the-cont/5266670#5266670)