# Add UserControl Dynamically in Panel Control asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am creating a website where user gives some value in textbox and clicks a button.

On the button click the UserControl should be added for number of time the user has given input.

What I did is,

```
    protected void btnSearchTaxi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            CustomDisplayList cus = new CustomDisplayList();
            cus.ID = "cus" + i;
            cus.Visible = true;
            pnlSearchResult.Controls.Add(cus);
        }
    }
```

CustomDisplayList is my user control which is complex control [mixture of labels, textbox, button].

```
<td style="width:20%;  font-family: Century Gothic; font-size:12px; color:White; text-
align:center;">Click to find<br/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchTaxi" runat="server" Text="Search Taxi" CssClass="googleButton"
Width="200px" onclick="btnSearchTaxi_Click" />
</td>


<td style="height:150px; width:100%; background-color: #FF6600">
                   <table style="height:100%; width:100%">
                   <tr><td style="color:White; font-size:30px; ">Search Result :</td></tr>
                   <tr><td><asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResult" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                   </td></tr>
                   </table>
</td>
```

The code was executed without any error, but the Control was not generated inside the panel.

Now I have changed the CODE to something like

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode = "Conditional" >
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="btnSearchTaxi" runat="server" Text="Search Taxi" CssClass="googleButton" Width="200px" onclick="btnSearchTaxi_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>


 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode = "Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResult" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="200px" BackColor="Aquamarine"></asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnSearchTaxi" EventName="Click"/>
         </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**But the still the Dynamic usercontrol are not getting created.**

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are plenty of duplicates on Stackoverflow and also many tutorials on the web. Basically you need to store the number of created controls somewhere, then recreate them always on postback(in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`).

Comment: Basically I am not a web programmer. But the value will be given by the user as a input and based on this the number of controls has to be generated. The problem is the code is getting executed but UI is not showing the controls.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter : Can you elaborate a little, I am not able to understand. I have moved button click code to Page_Init or Page_Load or pnlSearchResult_Init event; but still not able to show in the panel.

Comment: @AMITSHELKE: here is a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641070/dynamic-controls-missing-in-asp-net-application-on-postback-event-of-dynamic-con