# Pass dynamically created checkboxes in ASP.NET C# across multiple Postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck with a problem which I have reduced to code below . I have two buttons on an aspx page.
Both the buttons have `runat="server"` property and are inside `<form runat="server" >` tag

**btnGetData**

```
 protected void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            headlines = masg.Split('*');
            //Response.Write(headlines.Length);
            cb = new CheckBox[headlines.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < headlines.Length; i++)
            {
                cb[i] = new CheckBox();

                cb[i].Text = headlines[i];
                Literal br = new Literal();
                br.Text = "<br/>";
                Form.Controls.Add(cb[i]);
                Form.Controls.Add(br);
            }

 }
```

On clicking Get Data button , multiple checkboxes are generated with associated text .

I click on some of the checkboxes and then click on Show button which **IF WORKS CORRECTLY** should combine selected checboxes text into single string and display it.

**btnShow**

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



            for (int i = 0; i < headlines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (cb[i].Checked)
                    newmsg += cb[i].Text + '*';
            }
            Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>" + newmsg);

}
```

But once I click on GetData button , the  checkboxes are lost as they don't persist . I read about `SESSION` variables but can't figure out how to apply them . 
I have declared below variables as global so that they can be accessed throughout the page.

```
CheckBox[] cb;
string[] headlines;
string masg;
```

Please help with code .Please provide me with inputs in code. I will refine my question if I am not able to make something clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recreate dynamically created controls on every postback(in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`) due to the statelessness of HTTP. You need to know what you have to recreate. Therefore you can save the number of already created `CheckBoxes` in a `ViewState` variable.

You only need to assign the same IDs as before and add them in `Page_Load` at the latest. If you know the number of controls to create you can derive the ID from the counter variable by appending it to the control-id.

Recommandable readings:

- [TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
- [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Or you use one of the builtin [Data-Bound Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) that do this automatically. You only have to set their `DataSource` and call `DataBind`().

Here are answers of me on similar questions with implementation details:

- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276160/284240)
- [VB.NET (+ C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266482/load-dynamic-control-from-a-dropdownlist-event-handler-how-to-preserve-the-cont/5266670#5266670)

Comment: So dynamically created controls are wiped out on first button click ...But is there any way to pass the selected checkboxes to next button  ? i only need to generate checkboxes once ie on clicking GetData button

Comment: These controls don't exist anymore on the next postback. So you need to recreate them if you want to access their state(f.e. the `Checked` property) or if you want to handle their events(f.e. the `CheckedChanged`event). You could try it with `Request.Form[ ]` although i would prefer the clean approach and recreate them.

Comment: But won't the set of checkboxes be different if I recreate them ..the checkboxes I selected will be lost if i am understanding this correctly...?

Comment: @mhasan: No, that's the way ViewState works. You just need to create the control with the "correct" ID as before. Then the value will be loaded and events are triggered successfully. _Correct_ just means following: if you have 10 dynamical controls you need to know the number _10_. Then you can use this number to create controls with the ID `Checkbox_1` to `Checkbox_10`. Then you need to ensure that you recreate these checkboxes on the next postback. Hence you only have to store the _10_ in a `ViewState` or `Session` variable.

Comment: I went through viewstate.. it is not recommended if large data is being passed like in this case , will result in significant processing overhead , so won't be using it. can you plz provide me alternate ..thnks for bearing with me and my insufficient knowledge...

Comment: @mhasan: Please read the last sentence of my last comment again ;)

Comment: can you plz post some code...like how to implement it , in which button click event ??? plz..This topic is new for me..

Comment: @mhasan: I've provided examples in my answer. Just follow the two links at the bottom(_"implementation details"_).