# how to create array of panels in vb.net asp

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I need 3 panels. Instead of manually name this panels I want an array of panels? how can I do this in VB.net and ASP

in my ASP page I have

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Then in VB.net I generate an array of panels. which will be added to Panel1.
This is what I have so far (inside a loop)

```
Dim DivPanel() As Panel = Nothing
For i = 0 To 2
   DivPanel(i) = new panel
   DivPanel(i).controls.add(txtBox)
   Panel1.controls.add(DivPanel(i))
Next
```

I got an error at "DivPanel(i) = new panel" . 
The error is "NullReferenceException was caught"

please advice... thank you thank you very much

Comment: `Dim DivPanel() As Panel = Nothing` You need to create an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you've declared the array but you haven't initialized it here:

```
Dim DivPanel() As Panel = Nothing
```

However, you don't need that array at all:

```
For i = 0 To 2
   Dim panel = new Panel()
   Dim txtBox = new TextBox()
   panel.controls.add(txtBox)
   Panel1.controls.add(panel)
Next
```

Note that i have also created one `TextBox` for every panel, you cannot use the same instance.

Remember to recreate dynamically created control on every postback with the same ID as before in `Page_Load` at the latest. Threfore you need to know how many controls were already created. You could use the `ViewState` to persist the number.

Recommandable readings:

- [TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
- [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Or you use one of the builtin [Data-Bound Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) that do this automatically. You only have to set their `DataSource` and call `DataBind`().

Here are answers of me on similar questions with implementations:

- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276160/284240)
- [VB.NET (+ C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266482/load-dynamic-control-from-a-dropdownlist-event-handler-how-to-preserve-the-cont/5266670#5266670)